# What are the negative consequences of using a real class as the superclass, rather than an abstract class in simple factory pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

i use  simple factory pattern like this:

```
public class Father
{
    public virtual int field1;
    public virtual int Dosth()
    {

    }

}


public class Son:Father
{
    //inherit field1 from Father
    public override int Dosth();//override Father's method

    public string ex_field;
    public string string Ex_method()
    {
    }
}

public class Factory
{
    public static Father CreateObj(string condition)
    {
        switch(condition)
        {
            case("F"):
                return new Father();
            case("S"):
                return new Son();
            default:
                throw new exception("you have no choice");

        }

    }

}
```

in the code ,I use a real class instead of a abstract class as the factory class.
because the class Son just have something expand in Father Class base(most context can use father's ).if Father and Son inherit a abstract class by each.Class son can't inherit Father's fields and methods.
so my question is :anything not good will happen in future if write as fllow (i feel not good but can't find a better one )?
is there a better way?

Comment: thank you ,Chris Kooken.how can I format the code as they display in vs.net?how did you do it ?

Comment: To format the code you must put 4 spaces before each line of the code and it must be 2 lines away from any text (2 enter presses).

Comment: I suggest you don't use public fields, but use properties instead, because you can control their behavior. And I would change string condition with Enum, it would prevent missprints

Comment: I suggest that the title should be: Can classes inherit from other classes rather than only abstract classes? If so, can a simple factory pattern return an instance of either such class?

Comment: And I suggest that the question is: What are the negative consequences of using a real class as the superclass, rather than an abstract class?

Comment: thanks,I accept your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If your classes don't have that much in common use an interface and have the factory create objects that have a specific interface instead of a specific class

Create an interface with the common fields/methods and have both Father and Son implement it:

```
public interface IFamily
{
   int field1;
   int Dosth();
}

public class Father : AbstractA, IFamily
{
   // Implementation goes here
   int field1;
   int Dosth() {
      // Do magic
   }
}

public class Son : AbstractB, IFamily
{
   // Implementation goes here
   int field1;
   int Dosth() {
      // Do magic
   }
}
```

Your factory would then be:

```
public class Factory
{
    public static IFamily CreateObj(string condition)
    {
        switch(condition)
        {
            case("F"):
                return new Father();
            case("S"):
                return new Son();
            default:
                throw new exception("you have no choice");
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is preferred to creating deep inhertance hierarchies.

Comment: of course, i updated code examples to make it more clear what i meant, see Father & son classes